# Automatically include referenced model in Sequelize on each GET

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I have `user` model and `admin` model and they're associated as `user n:1 admin`. The code defining the `user` model as follows:

```
  // users.model.ts
  const users = sequelize.define('users', {
    ...
    adminId: {
      field: 'admin_id',
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    ...
  });

  (users as any).associate = function associate(models: any) {
    models.users.belongsTo(models.admins);
  };

  return users;
```

and the `admin` model:

```
  // admins.model.ts
  const admins = sequelizeClient.define('admins', {
    ...
  });

  (admins as any).associate = function associate(models: any) {
    models.admins.hasOne(models.users);
  };

  return admins;
```

Is it possible to implement some rule in the association, or some Sequelize hook f.e. `afterGet` that will automatically fetch the referenced record?

I would like to get the `admin` object as a property of the `user` object when I query just the User model, f.e. when I call `User.findOne(123)` it will have the object of the referenced `admin` record included. Basically telling Sequelize to always do the `JOIN` when getting the `user` record. Is that possible in Sequelize or I'll have to write logic separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I figured out that this is done through `scopes` (docs [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-addScope) and [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html)).

I added this to the `users.model.ts`:

```
  /*
   * When called as `model.scope('<scope_name>').<method>` it will override the default behaviour of Sequelize and
   * will add to the query whatever is requested in the scope definition.
   */
  users.addScope('includeAdmin', {
    include: [{
      attributes: ['id', 'name'],
      model: sequelize.models.admins,
      as: 'admin'
    }]
  });
```

Eventually, I will make the following call: `User.scope('includeAdmin').findOne(123)`, at which point Sequelize will automatically `JOIN` the `admins` model.

By default the `admin` entity's properties will be returned as such in the `user` object:

```
{
  "admin.id": ...,
  "admin.name": ...
}
```

So, if you want to have them as a nested `admin` object, then you must add `nest: true` property in the call, as follows: `User.scope('includeAdmin').findOne(123, {nest: true})`

If I want to make this behaviour default and not call `.scope('...')`, then when you declare the scope in the `.addScope()` function, call it `'defaultScope'`.

Answer (score 0):

That's why associations are used, to get things. To get the relation as attribute you can use [eager loading](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#eager-loading-example):

> ```
> const awesomeCaptain = await Captain.findOne({
>   where: {
>     name: "Jack Sparrow"
>   },
>   include: Ship
> });
> // Now the ship comes with it
> console.log('Name:', awesomeCaptain.name);
> console.log('Skill Level:', awesomeCaptain.skillLevel);
> console.log('Ship Name:', awesomeCaptain.ship.name);
> console.log('Amount of Sails:', awesomeCaptain.ship.amountOfSails);
> ```

Comment: I want to override the default behaviour of sequelize and make it automatically include the associated model.